# How to save activity state when closing an application? namely "webview"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

WebView. The question is how to implement the saving of the webview state (the state of the web page) and when the application is restarted, continue without re-requesting the page.
Such a function is for example Google Chrome browser, when closing and further opening the browser, the last page opens with all the data that was entered.
I would really appreciate your help friends !!!

It seems there is such an opportunity with SharedPreferences. But since I was a kettle, I could not figure it out.
I tried with "webView.saveState, webview.restoreState" but everywhere in the internet it says "how to save the state when the screen orientation changes", but I need to close the application ...

Comment: Use a cache https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-how-to-use-caching-in-webview.html

Answer (score 0):

Use onSaveInstanceState(). Its Called to retrieve per-instance state from an activity before being killed so that the state can be restored.

```
   protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
              //Get prefs and save data.
            }
```

Comment: it works only when the screen orientation changes, when the application is closed does not work

Comment: Then you can use onDestroy and onStop.